# Java filter words out of file even when rare none spaces occur

Tags: java, file, filtering, cpu-word

I am working on a big-data assignment for school and to make my code work I need to filter the words out of a text file.

Ofcourse I read the file and filter on things I do not need with replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

But this brings a problem. Because I filter on spaces and there are some special cases like:

```
wobbewy!'--'Wobbewy,'
```

I get words like:

```
wobbewywobbewy
```

Is there anyway to filter words on spaces and also filter out these special cases without making like an enormous amount of if statements?

Example code of what is happening after i tried the fix:

```
while ((thisLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] woord = thisLine.toString().trim().split("\\s+");
        for(int i=0; i<woord.length; i++){
            normalWord = woord[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
            normalWord = normalWord.toLowerCase();
```

Then i get outpuit like:

xxv (Multiple spaces)  my

Comment: Why dont you use ("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " "), so !'--' will be replaced with a space and splitting by space character will work. Alternatively: Do not replace anything and search the words using regex, for example by using the \w+ pattern.

Comment: Of course this entire problem gets a lot worse when dealing with languages that don't use whitespace for separating words. In some languages (Thai, IIRC?) simply breaking a block of text into words requires a dictionary and a recursive backtracking algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split consumes input, so split on "non word" chars:

```
String[] woord = thisLine.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

Notice I added the apostrophe to the chars to keep, which will let words like "don't" be treated as one word.

Answer (score 1):

When removing special characters, your information about word borders gets lost.

Change `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");` to `replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9]|\s)+", " ");` (replace special characters and white spaces to a single space).

Comment: That would create five spaces for the OP's example. I'd prefer `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"` and then split by space.

Comment: This example does not work and gives an error =) 

Might be me though but how would this work in a following scenario?:

    while ((thisLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] woord = thisLine.toString().trim().replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9]|\\s)+", " ");
         for(int i=0; i<woord.length; i++){
          normalWord = woord[i]
          normalWord = normalWord.toLowerCase();